# Flutter camera_windows: Device with same camera Id already exist. Dispose before creating another one

Tags: flutter, camera, flutter-windows

I have a desktop project which allow users to take picture using external camera.
I keep getting the following error when i use an external camera.
**Error**
flutter: CameraException(camera_error, Camera with given device id already exists. Existing camera must be disposed before creating it again.).

When i use the internal camera of the laptop i do no get this error. I have tried with different cameras and i still get the same error.

**My Code**
***Here i get all cameras***

```
  initCamera() async {
    try {
      if (controller != null) {
        await controller!.dispose();
      }
      cameras = await availableCameras();
      selectedCamera = cameras.isNotEmpty ? cameras[0] : null;
      setState(() {});
    } catch (e) {
      CustomDialog.showError(message: 'Camera Error');
    }
  }
```

***Here i change the camera from a dropdown of cameras***

```
void changeCamera(CameraDescription cameraDescription) async {
    if (controller != null) {
      await controller!.dispose();
    }

    setState(() {
      controller =
          CameraController(cameraDescription, ResolutionPreset.ultraHigh);
      selectedCamera = cameraDescription;
      isCameraOn = false;
    });
  }
```

***Here is where i initilize and start the camera***

```
 void startCamera() async {
    try {
      await controller?.dispose();
      controller = CameraController(
        selectedCamera!,
        ResolutionPreset.max,
        enableAudio: false,
      );
      await controller!.initialize();
      isCameraOn = true;
      setState(() {});
    } catch (e) {
      CustomDialog.showError(
          message: 'Camera error, Remove camera and try again');
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

***Here i dispose the camera***

```
  void disposeCurrentCamera() async {
    await controller?.dispose();
    controller = null;
    isCameraOn = false;
    setState(() {});
  }
```

***And i take the image here***

```
  snapPicture() async {
    if (!isCameraOn) {
      return;
    }
    final image= await controller!.takePicture();
    setState(() {
      isCameraOn = false;
    });
  }
```

when i use an external camera, its works once for the first time and get stack here

```
 controller = CameraController(
        selectedCamera!,
        ResolutionPreset.max,
        enableAudio: false,
      );
```

And it never works again even if i take it out and put it in back unless i kill the application and rerun it.

I have tried using different external cameras and it doesnt work.